# Can't pass param to the service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have problem with passing parameter from my concern to the Service object.

It shows me:

> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity. // it shows this as an info, cause i am skipping it
>
> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
>
> app/services/task_manager/task_destroyer.rb:6:in `initialize'

In my opinion i am passing parameter correctly:

// production_controller.rb

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

def destroy
  TaskManager::TaskDestroyer.new.destroy_task(params)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @tasks }
  end
end
```

// app/services/task_manager/task_destroyer.rb

```
module TaskManager
  class TaskDestroyer
    def initialize(params)
      @params = params
    end

    def destroy_task
      // code of the method i call
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing it incorrectly

```
TaskManager::TaskDestroyer.new(params).destroy_task
```

`new` passes it to the `initialize` method of the class